# Django: redirect after file download

Tags: django

I'm working on a view in my `Django 1.5` that allow me to download a file. The download process it's triggered by a button in the `HTML` page like this:

```
<a href="/file/download/{{ file.name }}/"><input type="button" value="Download!" /></a>
```

The url point to a view that manage the download:

```
def filedownload(request, filename):
    down_file = File.objects.get(name = filename)
    file_path = MEDIA_ROOT+str(down_file.file)
    file_name = down_file.filecomplete()
    if not Transaction.objects.filter(user = request.user, file = down_file):
        transaction = Transaction.objects.create(date = datetime.now(), user = request.user, file = down_file, vote = False)
        transaction.save()
    fp = open(file_path, 'rb')
    response = HttpResponse(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)
    if type is None:
        type = 'application/octet-stream'
    response['Content-Type'] = type
    response['Content-Length'] = str(os.stat(file_path).st_size)
    if encoding is not None:
        response['Content-Encoding'] = encoding
    if u'WebKit' in request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:
        filename_header = 'filename=%s' % file_name.encode('utf-8')
    elif u'MSIE' in request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:
        filename_header = ''
    else:
        filename_header = 'filename*=UTF-8\'\'%s' % urllib.quote(file_name.encode('utf-8'))
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; ' + filename_header
    return response
```

What I wanted to do it's to redirect the user to a success page right after they hit the downlad button but I can't find a way to do it.

I'm not concerned about interrupted or otherwise unsuccessful downloads since it's a school project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He are all steps that you have to follow to run your code :

get the [jQuery File Download](http://johnculviner.com/post/2012/03/22/Ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads-with-jQuery-File-Download.aspx) which allows downloads with OnSuccess and OnFailure callbacks.

Here is a simple use case demo using the plugin source with promises. The demo page includes many other, 'better UX' examples as well.

```
$.fileDownload('some/file.pdf')
    .done(function () { //redirect });
```

Here is a simple use case demo using the plugin [source](http://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js) with promises. The [demo page](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/) includes many other, 'better UX' examples as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `href` for the `input` to the download confirmation page you want to display, passing along the file name, then within the template for the confirmation page, set the `onload` event to redirect to actually do the download.

`<body onload=window.location='/file/download/{{ file.name }}/'>`

Comment: Doesn't work, the download isn't triggered for some reason. And, anyway, it's kind of a security risk, I can write the name of any file and simply download them even without the permissions!

Comment: By default, the content at the MEDIA_URL is publicly accessible.  If your downloads are sensitive, I would recommend against serving them from MEDIA_ROOT.  You could just load them directly from your file system in `filedownload`, and perhaps add a `@login_required` decorator to the view to control user access.  To pass the file name, you could POST it with the `input` submit, so the name isn't visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using ajax request waiting until the download fully successful.

in your view :

```
$.fileDownload('some/file.pdf')
    .done(function () { //redirect
                        window.location = '/link'; 
                        })
    .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });
```

Comment: I'll be honest, I have no idea how to work with that piece of code. I'm sure it's quite the solution but I don't know how to use it!

Answer (score 1):

How to use the previous code:

first add a name or id or class to your link
download link

next: here i use id to identify the link #a_d*

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).on("click", "#a_d", function () {
             $.fileDownload(.done(function () { //redirect
                                     window.location = '/link';})
             });
         });
</script>
```

done !!

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).on("click", "#downloadbutton", function () {
             $.fileDownload(.done(function () { //redirect
                                     window.location = '/confirmation/download/{{ name }}';})
             });
         });
 </script>` and `<a href="/file/download/{{ file.name }}/"><input type="button" value="Download!" id="downloadbutton" /></a>` dont work.