# Redirect or refresh page after file download Django

Tags: django, redirect, zip, httpresponse

i have some code to make zip and make it downloadable via browser

i try code from some reference, like make it refresh after download using jquery file download

[Django: redirect after file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827665/django-redirect-after-file-download)
https://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/

views.py

```
def backup(request):
...
...
if request.method == 'POST':
 ...
 ...
 zipper = shutil.make_archive(base_name = 
 os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,file_download), format = 'zip', root_dir = backup_dir, base_dir = './' )
 shutil.rmtree(backup_dir)
 resp = HttpResponse(open(zipper, 'rb').read(), content_type = "application/octet-stream")
 resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.zip' % file_download
 resp['Set-Cookie'] = 'fileDownload=true; Path=/'
 del_dir = os.getcwd()
 os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,file_download+'.zip'))
 formm.save()
 return resp
```

the file can be downloaded

and then i try add js to refresh

backup.html

```
<input id="file_download" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Backup" name="backup"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#file_download").click(function() {
    $.fileDownload($(this).prop('type'), {
      preparingMessageHtml: "The file download will begin shortly, please wait...",
      failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."
    });
    return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
  });
</script>
```

after add that js code the results is, pop up an box with "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."

---

error log

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 8485:tid 139715727099648] [remote 192.168.137.10:34003] Not Found: /submit
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source of the fileDownload plugin](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js#L74) reveals `successCallback` and `failCallback` options. To reload the page after successful download, try something like this:

```
$("#file_download").click(function() {
    $.fileDownload($(this).prop('type'), {
      preparingMessageHtml: "The file download will begin shortly, please wait...",
      failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again.",
      successCallback: function() { window.location.reload(true) }
    });
    return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
  });
```

Comment: still "The file download will begin shortly, please wait..."