# How can I return a redirect and file in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working on a form that when submitted has the option to export a PDF. This is great, but I would also like to be able to return a new URL for the user to be redirected to as well as downloading the file. Something that combines `render()` or `redirect()` with `FileResponse()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: redirect after file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827665/django-redirect-after-file-download)

Comment: This would work but I should mention that the file is uploaded to S3 and must stay private. The file can only be downloaded when the PDF is generated. Which is when the create form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you will need *two* views. One to serve the redirect and another one to serve the file to be downloaded. Here is a simplified implementation:

```
def myform(request):
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return redirect("/download/file.pdf")

def download(request):
    file = open("file.pdf", "rb")
    return FileResponse(file, as_attachment=True)
```